# Change Curl in php

Tags: php, curl

I have following code which is working fine in command line.

```
curl -F customerid=1 -F username=admin -F password=admin -F deviceid=ID5500 -F values=@/var/www/html/test/sample.xml http://192.168.100.27:8080/trafficinsight/api/v1/setdataxml
```

Now, I want to change it in PHP code, My code is below :

```
<?php
        $fields = array
        (
            'customerid'    =>1,
            'username'          =>'admin',
            'password'          =>'admin',
            'deviceid'          =>'ID5500',
            'values'            =>'@/var/www/html/test/sample.xml',
            'start'         =>'2016-05-24T16:00',
            'end'           =>'2016-05-24T17:00'
        );
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'http://192.168.100.27:8080/trafficinsight/api/v1/setdataxml' );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $fields ) );
        $result = curl_exec($ch );
        curl_close( $ch );

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); 


    die;


?>
```

My xml data is :

```
<data>
<datum time="2016-09-02T16:00" c1="1" c2="1" c3="1" c4="1"/>
<datum time="2016-09-02T17:00" c1="21" c2="1" c4="1"/>
<datum time="2016-09-02T18:00" c2="27"/>
<datum time="2016-09-02T16:00" c1="12" c2="21" c3="21" c4="7"/>
<datum time="2016-09-02T19:00" c1="29"/>
</data>
```

But its now working, I am getting error.

> [response] => ERROR
>    [responseCode] => 400

Comment: Is it possible the receiver of the request is expecting the post fields as json, or perhaps one of the fields should be a different format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `http_build_query()`, just give the array as the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` array. A file upload can't be put into a URL-encoded string.

```
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );
```

Also, the use of `@` in post fields is deprecated in PHP 5.5. If you're using 5.5.0 or newer, you should use the [`CURLFile`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) class.

```
    $fields = array
    (
        'customerid'    =>1,
        'username'      =>'admin',
        'password'      =>'admin',
        'deviceid'      =>'ID5500',
        'values'        => new CURLFile('/var/www/html/test/sample.xml', 'text/xml', 'sample.xml'),
        'start'         =>'2016-05-24T16:00',
        'end'           =>'2016-05-24T17:00'
    );
```